# How can I fix the platform of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

When I checkout my codes, the visual studio always make my platform to `Mixed Platform`:

[image]

My project settings resides at x64 platform only, so whether if visual studio make the platform to `Mixed Platform`, the project won't be built.

How can I fix the platform setting to `x64`?

Comment: The drop down should have Configuration Manager. Click on that and configure the project accordingly.

Comment: No,no,no. I means the settings should be stored in the solution file itself , I don’t want to change the platform setting every time when I checkout my codes. When I checkout my codes, its platform setting should be the ‘x64’, not the ‘Mixed platform ‘.

Comment: It should be stored on the sln file so once you make the change there will be a change in the sln (once you build) GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution .. Debug|Any CPU